# How to change value in array with index in react native

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

I have an array in my state:

```js
state = {
  some_array: [1,1,1,3,6,3,6,23], // sorry for the syntax it's changed
 }
```

Now I want to change value in that array that has index let's say 4, and in this case that would be number 6, or if I want to change index 1, that would be second number or array.
I know this is probabbly very simple but I'm just very confused.

If you need more info please comment.

Thanks!

Comment: Just do `state.some_array[indexHere] = newValue`

Comment: Shouldn't I use this.setState()?

Comment: @brk [react-docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state) says Never mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were immutable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think that you can  to  use next code:

```
const some_array = [...this.state.some_array]
some_array[indexHere] = yourValue
this.setState({some_array:some_array})
```

This example   --- true way for FP in react.

Comment: This is also correct way

Comment: It says ```TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property.```

Comment: @cmcodes , could you add your code?

Comment: some_array is assign to const